# Unable to send even dummy data to Google Analytics ecommerce in Magento 1.x

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, magento-1.9

I am trying to send some dummy data to google analytics account to make my understanding clear although I am in need to send real one too. But the issue is that I am unable to do so their is no error in console nor any data being posted to my google analytics account.

What i done is as follows:

1. Created account on google analytics, gave url of my local http://127.0.0.1/demo/
2. Enabled ecommerce in google analytics.
3. Magento backend : under system -> config -> google api, enabled the module and gave my google anlytic id (UA-XXXX-X).

In my head.phtml

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
 ga('require', 'ecommerce');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});

 ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});

 ga('ecommerce:send'); 
 </script>
```

Please suggest where I am wrong.
Trying to follow this [Ecommerce Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce) .. but got getting meaning of how to load eCommerce.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, confirm if the javascript code is being printed in the page source at all. I really doubt your javascript code is being printed since Magento uses .phtml file extensions instead of .php (front-end based). So there's a possibility you're not rewriting the file properly, or you haven't added your template file to the lay-out xml.

Comment: Ya it is printing very well, the file was head.phtml i typed it wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to run this from localhost? It may be the case this code only runs properly from a webserver

Comment: May be but as I have googled till we may use it even from localhost. Although in Google Analytic backend under realtime I am able to view no of user and curent url etc. But in ecommerce their seems nothing to appear.

Comment: How long did you wait it can take 24 - 48 hours for data to appear in the standard reports.

Comment: Ya I think you are absolutely correct. But one strange thing happened with me I am trying from almost 6 hrs I saw my data once and then it dissapeard again on relogin. Can you tell be whats wrong with this. Thanks a lot agin for replying.

Comment: Please ignore their was some change in my script. Thanks a lot